# What is the function of 一 in バスルーム and コンピュータ?

Tags: meaning, pronunciation, katakana, long-vowels

Is 一 in バスルーム and コンピュータ meant to indicate a drawn out vowel?　Like ba-su-ruuu-mu and kon-pi-yuuu-ta? Or is it a counter somehow? And it's the line radical (http://www.kanjidamage.com/kanji/1-one-line-radical-%E4%B8%80) right, and not a katakana like the other characters? Other examples include ヨーロッパ and オーストラリア.

Wasn't sure if it was related to this question: [Syntactic Properties of "Bare Numerals": 「一」in「其の一」](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/73036/syntactic-properties-of-bare-numerals-%e4%b8%80-in-%e5%85%b6%e3%81%ae%e4%b8%80)

Comment: To address your last comment, this character is not related to the 一 in 其の一 whatsoever, and no, it is not a counter. The ー you are asking about is an auxiliary character used with katakana, whereas 一 is a real Kanji that means "one", "1". They just happen to look very similar when written horizontally. When writing vertically, your "vowel elongator" character is placed vertical like this  |  , while the kanji for "one" is still written like this 一.

Comment: If you compare both characters carefully, you will see they are different in length: ー一

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's very surprising to me that this hasn't been answered somewhere on the site before, but after quite a bit of searching I can't find anything. This may just be so basic that it has slipped between the cracks.

The `ー` in these words (and generally in katakana words) represents an extension of the vowel before it. According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ch%C5%8Donpu), which is actually fairly informative in this case, it's called a `長音符`.

> The chōonpu is usually used to indicate a long vowel sound in katakana writing, rarely in hiragana writing, and never in romanized Japanese.

That said, I hear it referenced colloquially as `伸ばし棒` almost exclusively (as is mentioned on the [Japanese wiki page](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E9%95%B7%E9%9F%B3%E7%AC%A6)). I don't actually know a good name for this in English; I would probably just call it a vowel extension.