# I can write katakana and hiragana but I cannot piece together how i would write my own name in japanese due to a difficult sound in it

Tags: names

Okay, please go to google translate first and set the language on **Dutch**, After that type in "Joeri", The thing I just can't get to sound right in katakana writing is the "oe" sound. How should I write this or is this not possible?

Comment: But Dutch _oe_ is simply [[u]], right? Soeharto → スハルト, doek → ズック.

Comment: The problem i'm having is that with the japanese ウ you get a very short sound while oe is a longer sound. And I don't know how to do that.

Comment: See https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/77373/7810

Comment: Thanks, can't get the exact same sound, but a little closer.

Comment: @JoeriBrinks You will not get exactly the same sound, but this is to be expected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If we believe what [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Joeri) says:

> **Joeri** (/ˈjuːri/) is a Dutch transliteration of the Slavic masculine given name Yury (George) and as such a given name in Belgium and the Netherlands since the early 1960s.

The pronunciation (/ˈjuːri/) would be rendered ユーリ{HLL}. [ー represents long vowel](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/77373/7810) (mostly in foreign word). Note that Japanese ウ sound has less roundness and backness than typical [[u]], that means people (especially in Tokyo) would pronounce it more like "juuri" or "jeuri", but it can't be helped.

Comment: Alright thanks, that will do.

Answer (score 0):

I would write it out as ユゥリ. That would put more emphasis on the [oe] sound rather than ユーリ but not as much [u] sound if it was ユウリ.

-- Starfox